# Add comma to Selected Pop Up Fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I selected multiple fields from select box 1 and select box 2. Then hit the execute button, my alerts shows "AnimalBird,WolfFox".
I have googled how to make it add a comma when I select multiple fields when I hit the execute button, but no luck. I would like it to read "Animal,Bird,Wolf,Fox" with commas.
Below is my code
html:

```
<select name="select1" id="select1" size="4" multiple>
    <option value="1">Fruit</option>
    <option value="2">Animal</option>
    <option value="3">Bird</option>
    <option value="4">Car</option>
</select>
<select name="select2" id="select2" size="4" multiple>
    <option value="1">Banana</option>
    <option value="1">Apple</option>
    <option value="1">Orange</option>
    <option value="2">Wolf</option>
    <option value="2">Fox</option>
    <option value="2">Bear</option>
    <option value="3">Eagle</option>
    <option value="3">Hawk</option>
    <option value="4">BWM</option>
</select>

<input type="button" id="button" value="Execute" />
```

javascript:

```
$("#select1").change(function() { 
    if($(this).data('options') == undefined){
        /*Taking an array of all options-2 and 
            kind of embedding it on the select1*/
        $(this).data('options',$('#select2 option').clone());
    } 
    var id = $(this).val();

    console.log(id);

    var options = $(this).data('options').filter(function () {
        return $.inArray(this.value, id) > -1
    });
    $('#select2').html(options);
});

$('#button').click(function() {
    var str = $('#select1 option:selected').text() +','+ $('#select2 option:selected').text();
    alert(str);
});
```

If possible I would like the selected fields to show below the execute button.

Thank you everyone for your help.

Comment: Create an empty string, `.each` through the values and in the iteration add the value to the string with a comma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to loop through

http://jsfiddle.net/xd7pq22y/

```
$("#select1").change(function() { 
if($(this).data('options') == undefined){
    /*Taking an array of all options-2 and kind of embedding it on the select1*/
    $(this).data('options',$('#select2 option').clone());
    } 
var id = $(this).val();

    console.log(id);


    var options = $(this).data('options').filter(

    function () {
        return $.inArray(this.value, id) > -1
    });
    $('#select2').html(options);
});

$('#button').click(function() {
    var values = [];

     $('#select1 option:selected').each(function() {
        values.push($(this).text());
    });
    $('#select2 option:selected').each(function() {
        values.push($(this).text());
    });
    $("#wrapper").html(values.join(", "));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this, with a tidy way:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    var values = [];
    $('#select1 :selected, #select2 :selected').each(function() {
        values.push($(this).text());
    });
    alert(values.join(','));
});
```

---

#### What we use here is the below techniques:

1. `$().each()` method: Loop on the selected element set;
2. `Array.push()` method: Append one string to an array once;
3. `Array.join(separator)` method: just join the strings in the array;

Comment: Thanks All,  Fish_Ball the code is not running for some reason...I cant seem to get it to run

Comment: @Nguyenal07 See the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tp7d3L1v/1/. I should use alert rather than return in my code. Please check.